How does MEMORY_AND_DISK_DESER work for PySpark DataFrame?
Can someone explain the behaviour of the default MEMORY_AND_DISK_DESER storage level for PySpark DataFrame caching/persistence?
(It seems the default storage level for DataFrame used to be from MEMORY_AND_DISK?)
My understanding is that Python objects is (or were) stored serialized but wondering if that is still the case. Perhaps deserialisation is now the default, at least for cached Python objects in memory?
(Just to complicate matters, I think the default storage level for RDD is MEMORY_ONLY which is hopefully out-of-scope for this question!)
Two citations from the latest Spark 3.5.1 documentation (18 April 2024):

"In Python, stored objects will always be serialized with the Pickle
library, so it does not matter whether you choose a serialized level"

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence

"The default storage level has changed to MEMORY_AND_DISK_DESER to
match Scala in 3.0."

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cache.html
Thanks for your help!

I ran a small experiment with Databricks PySpark and it seems the default MEMORY_AND_DISK_DESER does behave differently and cache in-memory deserialised.
Test result, with size-in-memory of each cached DataFrame:

MEMORY_AND_DISK_DESER: 4.1Mb - Disk Memory Deserialized 1x Replicated
MEMORY_AND_DISK: 2.4Mb - Disk Memory Serialized 1x Replicated

Not sure how these storage levels affect disk serialisation though.
Steps

Run the code below in a Databricks notebook cell (fyi: I used Runtime 12.2)
Open the Databricks Spark UI "Storage" tab for the associated job cluster
Compare the two cached datasets Size in Memory attribute

%python

from pyspark import StorageLevel
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws, col, lit, rand, round

randy = rand(seed=0)

def create_df(storage_level, salt):
    df = spark.range(1, 1000000 + 1).withColumn("item_name", concat_ws(" ", lit(salt), round(randy * 1000)))
    df.persist(storage_level).count()
    return df

df1 = create_df(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_DESER, "df1")
df2 = create_df(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK, "df2")

Note: an identically sized salt value is used in each DataFrame to ensure uniqueness, to prevent Databricks silently re-using df1 as df2.
